# "Some JS files act more like libraries - they [...] never manipulate QML component instances directly" - middle ground?

Tags: javascript, qt, qml, language-interoperability

Quote from [Defining JavaScript Resources In QML](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-javascript-resources.html#shared-javascript-resources-libraries):

> Some JavaScript files act more like libraries - they provide a set of helper functions that take input and compute output, but never manipulate QML component instances directly.

What if I want a JS file that both:

- manipulates QML component instances (that are passed to it as arguments)
- doesn't get a copy of its code and data stored for every QML component instance that imports it?

I could get the "no data stored on every instance" part by, well, not putting global variables in the JS file. But, for some strange reason, a copy of the "code" part seems to be stored for every instance as well. I don't get why this is but I want to know whether I can circumvent it, and at what cost.

Comment: JS code can be somewhat mutable, so sharing it might not actually be what you want. I would avoid that until you have really good evidence that you need it, since you'll need copy-on-write(/assignment) to go along with it, so components don't change one another's behavior.

Comment: Can you please provide evidence for this statement: `But, for some strange reason, a copy of the "code" part seems to be stored for every instance as well.`

Comment: @Mitch: Well, the doc page I linked to says this right next: "As it would be wasteful for each QML component instance to have a unique copy of these libraries [...]"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the line you quoted from the documentation is incorrect, or at least very poorly worded; you can still have a JS file with `.pragma library` in it and manipulate QML objects that are passed in as arguments to its functions. The sentence was probably referring to the [previous section](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-javascript-resources.html#code-behind-implementation-resource).

Comment: Thanks, I tried it your way and it worked. Damn, those qt doc writers :) I'll report it to them.

Answer (score 1):

**To share data across qml files, consider using a qml [Singleton](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmlengine.html#qmlRegisterSingletonType).**

For data sharing purpose, I would not suggest using `.pragma library` (@Mitch) for following reasons.

1. `.pragma library` js provides **limited** functionality in qml object manipulation. While simple qml object manipulation (like property reading/writing) could be done with a `.pragma library` js, **it does NOT allow creating/deleting qml objects** (as you can in regular non-library js). It will suck when your application becomes dynamic.
2. `.pragma library` creating only one instance is merely an optimization in Qt implementation. It's **never** guaranteed that Qt creates exactly one instance, nor that your data would actually be shared.
3. Well, `.pragma library` is not designed to do data sharing work from the very beginning. Just, don't try to do it this way.